# Hash algorithm for user accounts passwords in macOS 10.12, 10.13, 10.14

Tags: password-hashing

I study this article: [How to Hack a Mac Password Without Changing It](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hacking-macos-hack-mac-password-without-changing-0189001/)
and get interested in what hash algorithm is used for hashing user accounts passwords in macOS 10.12+?

My hypothesis is that it is PBKDF-SHA512.

Comment: Your question has an answer in [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/what-type-of-hash-are-a-macs-password-stored-in)

Comment: Yeah, I 've seen it but in that question people discussed 10.11 version and I think, that something may be has been changed in latest versions of macOS 10.12+.

Comment: Well, the answer at the beginning says *valid in OS 10.8 and newer*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more about a specific version of software, and it is therefore better answered at the site where the OS is being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

As @kelalaka said, the answer is still valid as described [in this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/what-type-of-hash-are-a-macs-password-stored-in), so a PBKDF2-SHA512 hash with a large salt and iteration count in the 100000's, usually.

Comment: Is there any documentation about hashing user accounts passwords in macOS? for example how macOS choose number of iterations for hashing algorithm or generate random salt?

Comment: @Setplus part of it will be in the Unix part of the source code Apple releases, I think.

Comment: So, there are not any official documentation on number of iterations and random generator?

Comment: @Setplus not that I’m aware of. Only [this](https://www.apple.com/business/resources/docs/macOS_Security_Overview.pdf) which doesn’t mention the hashing I believe.

Comment: The answer says the iteration is 49504

Comment: @kelalaka the count depends on the machine.